# Spring Boot websocket handshake hanging intermittently

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Connecting to my web socket end point seems to (randomly) hang more often than not.

Here is the code that registers the endpoint -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketEndpointConfigurer implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketConfig webSocketConfig;

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketEndpoint webSocketEndpoint;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addHandler(webSocketEndpoint, webSocketConfig.getEndpoint()).setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

And here is my websocket end point -

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEndpoint extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getNoAppLogger(WebSocketEndpoint.class);

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Websocket connection created");
        //do more things
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
        //do things
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        //do things
    }
}
```

I'd say 50% of the time when i try to initiate the connection it is successful. The other 50% of the time it reaches the **afterConnectionEstablished()** method and I see my log message but it never returns to the browser and Chrome's debug tool says 'pending'.

If I restart my Spring Boot server sometimes it fixes it sometimes it doesn't, it is totally random. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance, this is really bugging me.

**EDIT:** I have tried this with multiple web socket testing clients and have the same results for all.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...

Our corporate anti-virus introduced a bug that affects web sockets....

Comment: Which anti-virus caused this bug?

Comment: https://forum.eset.com/topic/8355-protocol-filtering-breaks-websockets-after-update-at-5052016/